# ASP MVC ReidrectToRoute without query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

I use this code in Controller to `RedirectToRoute`

```
return RedirectToRoute(new
            {
                controller = "Posts",
                action = "Post",
                parametr1 = "11",
                parametr2 = "aaaaaaaa"
            });
```

The url output is something like this:

`https://localhost:45303/Posts/Post?parametr1=11&parametr2=aaaaaa`

But I want url output doesn't has any query string like this:

`https://localhost:45303/Posts/Post/1/aaaaaa`

And this is my route :

```
  routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default1",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{parametr1}/{parametr2}/{parametr3}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", parametr1 = UrlParameter.Optional, parametr2 = UrlParameter.Optional, parametr3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

How can do this?
I use `RedirectToRoute` and `RedirectToAction` but result is same.

Comment: You need to define a route in your `RouteConfig.cs` file - `url: {controller}/{action}/{parametr1}/{parametr2}`

Comment: You cant have 3 `UrlParameter.Optional` - only the last one can be optional. Remove `UrlParameter.Optional` from the first 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this overload for [RedirectToRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToRoute%28System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29) and provide proper route name:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Default1", new
        {
            controller = "Posts",
            action = "Post",
            parametr1 = "11",
            parametr2 = "aaaaaaaa"
        });
```